# Уменьшение одинаковых строк кода - Python

Tags: python

Всем привет, у меня есть 6 строчек следующего типа:

```
            brickQuantity -= int (quantityOfProducts)
            brickQuantityText = open ("source/brickQuantity.txt", "w")
            brickQuantityText.write (str (brickQuantity))
            brickQuantityText.close ()
            clear ()
            print (" Товар: Товар1 в размере \'" + str (quantityOfProducts) + "\' успешно куплено...")
```

У меня, допустим, будут написаны десять раз 6 таких строчек, в которых будут все одинаковые слова, кроме двух: (`brickQuantity , brickQuantityText`). Я пробовал создавать класс, в котором был конструктор следующего типа:

```
class Product:
    ThisQuantityOfProducts = brickQuantity
    FileQuantityOfProducts = brickQuantityText

    def set (self, ThisQuantityOfProducts, FileQuantityOfProducts):
        self.ThisQuantityOfProducts = ThisQuantityOfProducts
        self.FileQuantityOfProducts = FileQuantityOfProducts
```

И дальше я не понимаю как мне написать в классе те 6 строчек, чтобы я потом в коде создавал новые объекты на основе этого класса, и через функцию `set`, было исполнено те 6 строчек, но с другими двумя словами. Буду рад за подсказки.

Comment: Может банально использовать словарь вместо набора обычных переменных?

Comment: Можно подробнее?

Comment: Или как это вообще решит мою проблему?

Comment: А что это вообще за слова такие. Я не приведите участок кода где эти "слова" объявлены. Вернее откуда у вас берется само "brickQuantity". Потому как второе "слово" brickQuantityText может называться как угодно, потому что это вообще дескриптор файла в который вы пишите и его название никакой роли не играет. вот если вы открываете 6 файлов с разными названиями, тогда совсем другое дело ...

Answer (score 0):

Не понял до конца, что нужно, но код, если нужен класс, можно к такому виду привести:

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self):
        self.brick_quantity = {}

    def add_brick_quantity(self, quantity: int, filename: str = 'brickQuantity.txt'):
        self.brick_quantity[max(self.brick_quantity.keys() or [0, ]) + 1] = quantity
        with open(filename, 'a') as file:
            file.write(f'{quantity}\n')
            print (f"Товар: Товар1 в размере '{quantity}' успешно куплено...")

prod = Product()
prod.add_brick_quantity(10)
prod.add_brick_quantity(20)
prod.add_brick_quantity(30)
print(prod.brick_quantity)
```

В `self.brick_quantity` храним все `brick_quantity` со своим `id`, а на каждом вызове `add_brick_quantity()` добавляем в словарь новые данные по числу. Параллельно отписываем в текстовик нужные данные.

Answer (score 0):

Можно более-менее универсальную функцию написать. Хотя, наверное, лучше куда-то в сторону классов смотреть:

```
def buy_product(somethingQuantity, somethingQuantityText, somethingQuantityFile,  quantityOfProducts):
    somethingQuantity -= int (quantityOfProducts)
    with open (f"source/{somethingQuantityFile}.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write (str (somethingQuantity))
    clear ()
    print (f" Товар: {somethingQuantityText} в размере {quantityOfProducts} успешно куплено...")
    return somethingQuantity

brickQuantity = buy_product(brickQuantity, "Кирпичи", "brick", brickQuantityOfProducts)
boardQuantity = buy_product(boardQuantity, "Доски", "board", boardQuantityOfProducts)
...
```

Comment: А где Вы используете переменную ```brickQuantityOfProducts```, или где она создается?